# ASP.NET Page Not Found Error in New Page with Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, code-behind

I inherent a large ASP.NET web form application and try to add a new test.aspx page with code behind to a newly created folder - test.

Test.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>
```

test.aspx.cs:

```
using System;

public partial class Test: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("This is a test");
    }
}
```

In my web.config file, I make the Test folder be accessible to anyone.

```
  <location path="Test">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

When I access it in my development machine using https://localhost/Test/Test.aspx.  It works fine.  But after I deployed to my server.  I got error 404 - page can not be found when I do https://myserver/Test/Test.aspx.

The server is Windows 2008 R2.  All other existing pages serve fine except for this new one.

Put another new page Test1.aspx without code behind in the same Test folder.

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Write("hello, world!");
}
</script>
```

https://myserver/Test/Test1.aspx.  It returns me "hello, World!".

Put any image file in the same folder is accessible also. https://myserver/Test/test.gif.

What could be wrong for a simple new .aspx page with codebehind?  I do not see anything in Windows event log or IIS log.  How to debug this problem?

Please help

Comment: Do you have any rewrites for path /Test.aspx ?

Comment: @Boney, that is a new folder and new file.  I have not put any rewrites rule anywhere.

Comment: Could you change `CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" ` to `CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" `, and see it work?

Comment: @Win, that is the fix.  I did not notice that CodeFile, instead of CodeBehind, is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moved from comment.*

Replacing ***CodeFile*** with ***CodeBehind*** solves the problem.

Basically, we use ***CodeBehind*** if we need to compile in Visual Studio before deployment.

[CodeFile and Code-Behind](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/codefile-and-code-behind/187202007)